# node.js asynchronous understatement via simple example

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

(Taken from exam)

```
    setTimeout(function(){
console.log("A");
},1000);

//Some cpu heavy calculations
console.log("B");
```

Assuming the cpu code takes 0.5 minutes, what should be printed first?

does the cpu calculations has to run in asynchronous way ? or we can't assume that? 
as I understand , node.js runs the code in synchronous  way, unless its specific asynchronous function, am I wrong?

Thanks, and sorry if the question is too obvious...

Comment: The code outside the timeout should execute first, the timeout is executed when the thread is free, or in a second at the earliest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node is single threaded. So any CPU intensive tasks are going to block execution. Either way, `B` will be printed before `A`.

An asynchronous function just delays execution of the task until later in the thread. Take for example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('A');
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  // CPU intensive calculations
}, 2000);

console.log('B');
```

What you'll see is `B`, `A` then the computation. But each one is blocking. Don't confuse "asynchronous" with "threaded".

Node can do a lot of things in a non-blocking way because of the underlying library [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) which is threaded and handles all that I/O for you in the background. And users can achieve the same results if they are willing to learn how to write native (i.e. C++) modules that take advantage of libuv's thread pool. Where they can defer CPU intensive work in that same non-blocking way.